# System.Type; implicit cast to string

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, system.type

While looking at the **System.Type** class under the Code Definition Window, I cannot seem to understand how an instance of this class is implicitly cast to string. For example, on the following code:

```
int foo = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Hi! I'm a type of type {0}", foo.GetType());
```

How was the System.Type resulting from GetType() implicitly cast to string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not being implicitly cast to string. It's being converted to `Object` (with the standard implicit reference conversion), and `String.Format` is formatting it appropriately - by calling `ToString` in this case.

This is *not* being done at compile-time. The code you've shown calls the [`Console.WriteLine(string, object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf.aspx) overload.

Comment: @lagerdalek: I think I'm going to retire Tony some time this week, and go back to being me.

Comment: Duh, yeah it's calling one of the overloaded WriteLine() methods. Thanks for pointing that out. Missed that, I read it as Console.WriteLine("blablah"+foo.GetType()); Now, we would prolly get a compile error there...hmm.

Comment: No, we wouldn't - because of the way string concatenation works. That's a different question though :)